# How to truncate decimal value without loosing precision

Tags: php, decimal, truncate

I have current variable php:

```
$latlng = "<a href='http://www.google.com/maps/place/".$lat.",".$lng."/@".$lat.",".$lng.",".$zoom."' target='_blank'>Lat ".$lat." Lng ".$lng."</a>";
```

echo output is as following example:

[image: Lat 39.959146953575164 Lng 16.380643111639415]

i want truncate it so at end i want have following result:

[image: Lat 39.959 Lng 16.380]

I have tried following code but it cut only final part:

```
$cut_string = substr($latlng,0,strpos($latlng,'</a>')-12);
echo "$cut_string <br/>\r\n";
```

[image: Lat 39.959146953575164 Lng 16.380]

Thanks

Comment: Try `round(16.380643111639415, 3);`

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php format as float in string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand your problem.
You want the link with full precision but a easy to read link text?

This should be what you need:

```
$latlng = "<a href='http://www.google.com/maps/place/".$lat.",".$lng."/@".$lat.",".$lng.",".$zoom."' target='_blank'>Lat ".round($lat,3)." Lng ".round($lng,3)."</a>";
```

As you can see the link to google is intact but the text is rounded to three decimals.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `round`, but you will loose precision. If that works, then

```
echo round(39.959082, 3);
```

But, using `substr`, you could maintain the precision.

```
$lat = "39.959082";
echo substr($lat,0,strrpos($lat,'.')+4);
```

will display

```
39.959
```

Comment: yes but i want output Lat 39.959 Lng 16.380 not only Lat 39.959 linkable

Comment: ah ok but  in this mode link lost precision because missing some decimals?

Comment: @grigione I didn't get you. I was mentioning about round. Because round will round-up the decimal to nearest digit.

Comment: ok.. but i'm waiting if someone find other solution Your solution don't satisfy me completely because at end i get link : https://www.google.com/maps/place/39.959,16.380/@39.959,16.380, instead of https://www.google.com/maps/place/39.959146953575164,16.380643111639415/@39.959146953575164,16.380643111639415,

Comment: @grigione instead of ??

Comment: @grigione I didn't get you, you said, you need `39.959082` to be `39.959`. right ??

Comment: Andreas have got correct solution howeveer i gave you a vote positive thanks sorry if I'm not very clear for my bad english

Comment: @grigione no problem.