# How to get two digit decimal number without change of second digit decimal (1.255 => 1.25)?

Tags: php

I know one function "round()" that it gives me a two-digit decimal number. But the problem is that this will changed the second decimal digit according to the third decimal digit of the number.
For example, if the number is 1.255 and we used function round below code.

```
echo round(1.255, 2);
```

And the result will be below.

> 1.26

But I want result like below.

> 1.25

Please help me if anyone knows other function that will do this thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to truncate decimal value without loosing precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46503823/how-to-truncate-decimal-value-without-loosing-precision)

Comment: I have checked it but this is not relevant for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use string functions like [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and [strpos()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

```
<?php

$str = strval(1.255);
echo substr($str,0,strpos($str,".")  === false ? strlen($str) : strpos($str,".") + 3);
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/12E48

Comment: Updated with  strict check `===`  instead of `==`.